# Insert a row to google fusion table using php

Tags: php, http, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I looked throught the documentation for google fusion tables. There's quite clear syntax for inserting rows but I couldn't managed how should I call it? 
[fussion tables insert row (documentation)](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference#insertRow)
I have table, its set public and I have its id, I can show the map with markers using php and javascript.

Problem I'm dealing with is how to use the queries for fusion tables. How should I call them from php?
For example If you are working with mysql database you use something for example mysqli, connect to the database, call the query and its done. 
There is some info in documentation about http request but I don't have any clue how to call the queries, which are pretty clear from php. 
I mean ations like:

1. connect to the table with id
2. call the query
3. get results of the query (ok fail)

Lets suppose I have simple public which have id, name(of the place), latitude, longitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [Google API Client for PHP](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client), which is a library to connect to different Google services including Google Fusion Tables.

There is a ["Getting Started" page](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started), which explains how to use the library. Some time ago, I created [some PHP examples](https://github.com/metaodi/GFTPrototype/tree/master/examples/php), but I'm not sure if they are still working. But maybe they help you to head in the right direction.

**Update 11.1.2017:** I recently [updated my examples and put them in a separate repository](https://github.com/metaodi/GFTExamples). Maybe they are of some help for someone, that stumbles upon this question.

Comment: God bless you, Odi for those examples.

Comment: Btw I would avoid fussion tables today, it's so much annoying work around it, its better use some marker example from google map development examples. It worked for me. I just have my own database with latitude and longitude and it workes fine with markers too ... 
(Just comment for somebody who would decide between fussion tables and markers like I was)